# Реализация макета сайта

Tags: javascript, css, html5

[image: Пример макета]
Как реализовать данный макет сайта-многостраничника. Красная область всегда одинаковая(меню и футер), а между ними просто белый фон. А синяя область должна находиться поверх красных и может иметь разную высоту, и в ней меняется контент(home, blog, contacts ...). Буду благодарен, если подскажите примерную структуру разметки страницы.

Comment: То есть даже если в синей области ничего нет, она все равно должна растягиваться от хедера до футера?

Comment: Растяжение зависит от синей области, если там пусто, то просто будет хедер и сразу футер. Но перекрытие красных всегда одинаковое.

Comment: адаптив? Отступы от краев у контентной области есть?

Comment: Да адаптив. max-width серой области 1020px, max-width синей 940px, padding: 25px у синей.

Answer (score 0):

Последнее время использую структуру типа такой .... не уверен, что правильно воспроизвел, но вроде пока проблем не увидел (не думаю, что тут можно адекватно это показать, проще скопировать к себе и посмотреть). Подобная сетка меняется от проекта к проекту, но для многих "лендингов" и прочего подходит.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* убираем стандартный margin */
  background-color: grey;
}

/* Магия, что бы прижать футер вниз, даже если контента нет */
.page {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.page_row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* "Строка" в которой контент растягиваем на всю высоту оставшуюся от футера и хедера */
.page_row:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100%;
}

/* /конец_магии */

.header, .footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}

/*
*  Что бы внутренний margin не влиял на
*  внешнее расположение родителя
*/
.content {
  padding: .1px;
}

.content_inner {
  position: relative; /* Без этого "нижний блок" родителя будет перекрывать */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 950px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: -40px auto; /* Что бы контент "залезал" на соседние блоки родителя по вертикали */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="page_row">
    <header class="header"></header>
  </div>
  <div class="page_row">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content_inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page_row">
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```